# GCC turning on O2 causes bug when 128-bit integer is subscripted

Tags: c++, gcc

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

__int128 idx;

int main() {
    int a[2] = {1, 2};
    idx++;
    a[idx] = 0;
    printf("%d %d", a[0], a[1]);
}
```

After turning on O2 a[idx] = 0 not executed.
I guess it shouldn't be undefined behavior.
Is this a bug in the compiler?

https://godbolt.org/z/qqccd9oEj

Comment: Idx is uninizialized so what do you expect?

Comment: @gerum `idx` is global so is initialized to 0

Comment: Just to note that adding [`-Werror -Wpedantic`](https://godbolt.org/z/6GP5WbWe4) does cause the diagnostic `error: ISO C++ does not support '__int128' for 'idx' [-Werror=pedantic]`.

Comment: @Kevin Even for non-standard types?

Comment: @gerum All types: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.start.static#2

Comment: @G.M. pedantic and compiler extensions don't mix.

Comment: `a[static_cast<std::size_t>(idx)] = 0;` to fix it.  (I know that's not what is being asked.)

Comment: Interestingly, it works if you do `idx = 1;` instead of `idx++;`

Comment: Going by godbolt, it looks like this behavior started with gcc 9.1

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the compiler output for gcc-12.1 -std=c++20 -O2 -W -Wall

```
.LC0:
        .string "%d %d"
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edx, 2
        add     QWORD PTR idx[rip], 1
        mov     esi, 1
        adc     QWORD PTR idx[rip+8], 0
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
idx:
        .zero   16
```

The problem is `mov edx, 2`. That is just wrong, it should read `a[1]` and optimize that to 0 not 2.

clang gets it right but still generates horrible code. `idx` should get optimized out.

You should file that as compiler bug.

Comment: `add QWORD PTR idx[rip], 1` and `adc QWORD PTR idx[rip+8], 0` is 128-bit integer addition.

Comment: Ups, you are right, that's `++idx`

Comment: idx should not get optimized out because it is visible to other compilation units (and could be set to -1 before main starts)

Comment: Only if there are any other compilation units. Although there always is libc.so... But `idx` remains even if you declare it static.

Comment: IIRC `xor eax eax` before `printf` mean no vector arguments is it not?

Comment: @zahir No, it means no double arguments (floating point registers).